# How can we add a tooltip on series name of Amcharts?

Tags: javascript, angular, amcharts, amcharts4

[image]

How to add a tooltip on hover of the series name of Amchart. (Want to add tooltip on hover on selected area in the attached screenshot).

Adding a series name like :

```
let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.name = q1.seriesName;
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way. I don't know why one has to use a `setTimeout`. Without it, the `values` array is empty when the chart loads.

```
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
setTimeout(function() {
  chart.legend.itemContainers.values[0].tooltipText = 
    "The [bold {color}]{name}[/] series is awesome!";
  chart.legend.itemContainers.values[1].tooltipText = 
    "The [bold {color}]{name}[/] series is cool!";
  chart.legend.itemContainers.values[2].tooltipText = 
    "The [bold {color}]{name}[/] series is nice!";
}, 500);
```

[image]

Comment: The timeout is needed because AmCharts creates everything asynchronously. If you want to set a default value on all the itemContainers, use a template, e.g. `chart.legend.itemContainers.template.tooltipText = "[bold {color}]{name}[/] "`. If you to set individual values without a timeout, use the ready event instead (`chart.events.on('ready', () => { chart.legend.itemContainers.each((container) => { container.tooltipText = "..." } ) })`). Note that `values` is read-only and should not be manipulated directly - use `each` or `for ... of`.

Comment: Thank you @Stephane. The solution worked perfectly!

Comment: And Thanks @xorspark, I added that code under chart.events.on('ready', () =>{